# How to enter data in child popup window fields and click ok button , when click radio button at main window

Tags: java, selenium, autoit

**Step1** : Click on radio button at main window
**Step2** : Small popup window was raised
**Step3** : should enter data in text fields and click ok button
**Step4** : The small window should close and return to main window .

I have tried using the switch handle concept in java - selenium web driver but not worked as expected . 
could any one suggest any solution

Comment: can you please provide more info..why it dint work?getting any error?

Comment: you can use images or code to explain ur problem in a better way..

Answer (score 0):

you can use javax.swing.JOptionPane to complete it with a function showInputDialog()

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Autoit Window commands dont forget to set

```
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also
```

in order to detect children.